# How to Data migration from VirtueMart 1.1.x to VirtueMart 2.5.x?

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart, data-migration

How to Data migration from VirtueMart 1.1.x to VirtueMart 2.5.x ?

I need to Migrate/update website with data and database from virtuemart 1 to virtuemart 2? vm1 to vm2

so, How can do easily ?

Help Me.

Comment: what have u done? may be some searching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jignesh.

Hope this will help you to migrate virtuemart.

http://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/virtuemart-11-to-version-2/